# Most flexible minimizer/compressor for ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, optimization, compression, minify

From your experience, what's the most flexible minimizer/compressor (JS+CSS) for ASP.NET MVC you've dealt with?

So far

- [mbcompress](http://mbcompression.codeplex.com) doesn't seem to be too MVC friendly
- [weboptimizer.codeplex.com](http://weboptimizer.codeplex.com) lacks documentation
- [clientdependency.codeplex.com](http://clientdependency.codeplex.com) <strike>is still in beta</strike>
- [compress2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/combres2.aspx) seems like a good candidate, but haven't tried it yet
- [mvcscriptmanager](http://mvcscriptmanager.codeplex.com/) only combines and compresses javascript but not CSS

By flexible I mean

- Choose what should be compressed, minified, and combined
- Add exceptions. E.g. if debug don't compress XYZ.JS or don't minify ABC.CSS
- Caching
- In the end, it should help offer the best YSLOW score.

If you know of any other assemblies out there, please list them also.

Answer (score 1):

ClientDependency is not in beta anymore and works well with MVC, I think is a very good candidate. AFAIK it does not use YUI but you can plug your own compressor.

Answer (score 0):

I personally find the C# port of [YUI Compressor](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/) to be the best of the best when it comes to CSS and JavaScript minification. In the end, though, you're going to have to do the leg work to get a perfect YSLOW score. There's no library that you can just drag and drop and it will magically make your website fast. Look into making a controller for your content and doing the following:

- [GZIP your response](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/102969.aspx)
- Far Future Expire: HttpResponse.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddYears(5);

Comment: Most of the frameworks/libraries aforementioned do make use of the YUI compressor port. Although magic would be nice, I am most definitely trying to avoid wheel reinvention and learn from what others have experienced with previous efforts.